# Beam Flatten receives input but no output

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have Beam / Dataflow streaming pipeline (unbounded stream from Pubsub) that diverges by filtering (plus some intermediate processing, windowing and grouping) and eventually converges using Flatten to write data in the DB.

[image]

The two PTransforms converging have the same output (`PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>>`). The problems are:

1. `merge_pipeline_branches` PTransform starts grayed out when all other PTransforms are in green, and remains grayed out all throughout.
2. No emitted output from the `merge_pipeline_branches` PTransform going to `write_data`, although it receives input. Admittedly, only the left upstream PTransform streams data into it; the right one does not generate data yet.

Here is the code snippet:

```
// Merge the two writable PCollections
PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> toWrite1 = ...
PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> toWrite2 = ...

PCollectionList<KV<String, GenericRecord>> collections = PCollectionList.of(toWrite1).and(toWrite2);

PCollection<KV<String, GenericRecord>> merged = collections
        .apply("merge_pipeline_branches", Flatten.<KV<String, GenericRecord>>pCollections())

merge.apply("write_data", ...);
```

I read the documentation for `PCollectionList::and` and it says:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollectionList.html#and-org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection-

```
Returns a new PCollectionList that has all the PCollections of this PCollectionList 
plus the given PCollection appended to the end.
```

Please clarify:
Does this mean the `merge_pipeline_branches` waits for both the two upstream PTransforms to have data in order for it to start streaming the output?

If that is the case, that is not the behavior that I want to happen. I simply want to merge the streaming, not the data themselves. I want to funnel the outputs of the two upstream PTransforms into `write_data` continuously and independent of each other.

Am I using the correct class/method, which is `Flatten.<T>pCollections()`? Or should I use a different paradigm for achieving what I want?